# MySQL string Dynamic Replace

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a TEXT field that contains a lot of text, at some point I have `== Gallery == Random text ==Source==`.

I want to know if there is a way to replace `== Gallery == Random Text` with nothing (just remove) with just MySQL ?

Currently working with this update

```
update `wiki_article_revisions` 
set `opcode` = replace(`opcode`, '== Gallery == ==Sources==', '');
```

but I can't find a way to detect the random text between those two text snippets.

Comment: Are you using MySQL with PHP?

Comment: Yes, but I`m looking for a mysql solution and since this only will be done once manually for all content in that table by me, performance won't be a issue.

Comment: You want to remove all the text starting from == Gallery == to == Sources ==?

Answer (score 1):

You can't there is no function in MySQL supporting UPDATE with regex([How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986826/2727656)). You have to load the content to a string then performe a php regex replace to the string with php to remove the randome text the update with the new content:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM wiki_article_revisions");

$regex = '/(\(== gallery ==\))([^\0]*)(\(== source ==\))/';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    preg_replace($regex, "$2", $row['opcode']);
    $mysqli_query("UPDATE wiki_article_revisions SET opcode=" . $row['opcode'] . "WHERE id=" . $row['id']);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually construct the string, with something like:

```
select concat(left(val, locate('== Gallery == ', val) - 1),
              substring(val, locate('==Source==', val) + 10)
             )
```

This assumes that the delimiters each only appear once in the overall string.

As an `update` this would be:

```
update `wiki_article_revisions` 
    set `opcode` = concat(left(opcode, locate('== Gallery == ', opcode) - 1),
                          substring(opcode, locate('==Source==', opcode) + 10)
                         );
```

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

```
update `wiki_article_revisions` 
set `opcode` = REPLACE(opcode, '== Gallery == ==Sources==', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE wiki_article_revisions
SET opcode = REPLACE(opcode,SUBSTRING_INDEX(opcode,'==',3),'')
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfb444/1)

Assuming the **number of `==` instances is equal** on all rows.If you want just the random text:

```
UPDATE wiki_article_revisions
SET opcode = (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(opcode,'==',3),'==',-1))
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec9c32/1)